# VERTRES and HORZRES depends on scaling setting when system booted up

Tags: winapi, windows-10, dpi-aware

I've been recently playing with WINAPI to retrieve scaling setting and screen resolution and I came across this strange behaviour.

I've got small C++ program (listing available below) that retrieves values of VERTRES, HORZRES, DESKTOPVERTRES and DESKTOPHORZRES. My program also sets DPI awareness mode to 1 (system level awareness). I noticed that values reported by  VERTRES, HORZRES depends on the system scaling factor used on system start up.

So on my laptop I have configured system scaling factor to 150% and resolution as 1920x1080. That is the configuration on start up. When I retrieve HORZRES and DESKTOPHORZRES both values are reported as 1920.

If I change scaling setting to 100% and don't reboot my computer, next time when I retrieve these values they are reported as 2880 (for HORZRES) and 1920 (for DESKTOPHORZRES).

After I reboot my computer with scaling settings set to 100% both values are reported at 1920  again.

If I change scaling to 150% again, values are reported as 1280 (HORZRES) and 1920 (DESKTOPHORZRES).

The described behaviour only observed when I'm setting DPI awareness to 1, if it is set to 0 ("not aware") or 2 ("per screen awareness") values are always reported as 1280 (HORZRES) and 1920(DESKTOPHORZRES) regardless of how scaling was configured on start up.

I was wondering why does the value reported by HORZRES (or VERTRES) depends on a scaling factor used on system start up? Is that expected behaviour?

If above has already been described somewhere, l'd appreciate any references.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cerrno>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <math.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <shellscalingapi.h>
#include <winuser.h>

class Rectangular
{
public:
    Rectangular(int height, int width) : height(height), width(width) {};
    const int height;
    const int width;
};

class MonitorInfo
{
public:
    MonitorInfo(std::string device_name, Rectangular logical_resolution, Rectangular physical_resolution, Rectangular physical_size_mm) :
        device_name(device_name), logical_resolution(logical_resolution), physical_resolution(physical_resolution),
        physical_size_mm(physical_size_mm), scaling(static_cast<int>(std::round(100.0*(float)physical_resolution.height / (float)logical_resolution.height))) {};

    void print_to_stdout() const;
    const std::string device_name;
    const Rectangular logical_resolution;
    const Rectangular physical_resolution;
    const Rectangular physical_size_mm;
    const int scaling;
};


class MonitorsInformation
{
public:
    MonitorsInformation();
    const std::vector<MonitorInfo>& get_monitors_info() const { return monitors; }
    std::string get_last_error_string() const { return last_error; }
    Rectangular get_monitors_rectangular() const;
private:
    RECT rectangular_combined;
    std::vector<MonitorInfo> monitors;
    std::string  last_error;
    static BOOL CALLBACK MonitorEnum(HMONITOR hMon, HDC hdc, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM pData);
};

void MonitorInfo::print_to_stdout() const
{
    std::cout << "\nDevice: " << device_name << "\nLogical Screen resolution: " << logical_resolution.width << "x" << logical_resolution.height;
    std::cout << "\nPhysical Screen resolution: " << physical_resolution.width << "x" << physical_resolution.height;
    std::cout << "\nDPI ratio: " << scaling;
    std::cout << "\nPhysical Size(mm): " << physical_size_mm.width << "x" << physical_size_mm.height << "\n";
}


MonitorsInformation::MonitorsInformation() : rectangular_combined(RECT()), last_error(std::string()), monitors(std::vector<MonitorInfo>())
{
    EnumDisplayMonitors(0, 0, MonitorEnum, (LPARAM)this);
}

BOOL CALLBACK MonitorsInformation::MonitorEnum(HMONITOR hMon, HDC hdc, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM pData)
{
    MonitorsInformation* pThis = reinterpret_cast<MonitorsInformation*>(pData);

    MONITORINFOEXA monitor_info;
    monitor_info.cbSize = sizeof(MONITORINFOEXA);

    if (!GetMonitorInfoA(hMon, &monitor_info))
    {
        pThis->last_error = "GetMonitorInfoA failed with error: " + errno;
        return FALSE;
    }

    UnionRect(&pThis->rectangular_combined, &pThis->rectangular_combined, lprcMonitor);

    HDC device_context = CreateDCA(NULL, monitor_info.szDevice, NULL, NULL);

    int LogicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(device_context, VERTRES);
    int LogicalScreenWidth = GetDeviceCaps(device_context, HORZRES);
    int PhysicalScreenHeight = GetDeviceCaps(device_context, DESKTOPVERTRES);
    int PhysicalScreenWidth = GetDeviceCaps(device_context, DESKTOPHORZRES);

    pThis->monitors.push_back(
        MonitorInfo(
            std::string(monitor_info.szDevice),
            Rectangular(
                LogicalScreenHeight,
                LogicalScreenWidth),
            Rectangular(
                PhysicalScreenHeight,
                PhysicalScreenWidth),
            Rectangular(
                GetDeviceCaps(device_context, VERTSIZE),
                GetDeviceCaps(device_context, HORZSIZE))));

    return TRUE;
}

Rectangular MonitorsInformation::get_monitors_rectangular() const
{
    return Rectangular(
        std::abs(rectangular_combined.top) + std::abs(rectangular_combined.bottom),
        std::abs(rectangular_combined.left) + std::abs(rectangular_combined.right));
}


int main()
{
    SetProcessDPIAware();

    for (;;)
    {
        MonitorsInformation MonitorsInfo;
        char exit_char = 'N';
        std::cout << "You have " << MonitorsInfo.get_monitors_info().size() << " monitors connected.\n";
        printf("Screen rectangular. %d x %d\n",
            MonitorsInfo.get_monitors_rectangular().width, MonitorsInfo.get_monitors_rectangular().height);

        for (auto &monitor : MonitorsInfo.get_monitors_info())
        {
            monitor.print_to_stdout();
        }
        std::cout << "Would you like to repeat? [Y]/[N]\n";
        std::cin >> exit_char;
        if (exit_char == 'N' || exit_char == 'n')
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Lots of things go weird unless you reboot (or at least logout) after changing DPI. It is what it is.

Comment: I set DPI awareness using `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_UNAWARE);` and `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_SYSTEM_AWARE);` both can't reproduce your issues. The HORZRES value always decreases when the scale factor increase. (100%-1920; 125%-1536; 150%-1280; 175%-1097) I don't reboot.

Comment: I test on Windows 10 Enterprise Desktop.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT,thanks for your input. Yes, I can see the same behaviour if I increase scaling factor from default 100% to e.g. 150%. In this case I see that HORZRES is getting smaller (as I would expect). My problem is happening when I keep scaling factor to 150% and power cycle my computer.

Answer (score 1):

@AlexanderZinovyev Thanks for further explanation and I can reproduce your issue with keeping scaling factor to 150% and power cycle my computer.

After check the [GetDeviceCaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getdevicecaps) API document I found the following note:

> Note  GetDeviceCaps reports info that the display driver provides. **If
>   the display driver declines to report any info, GetDeviceCaps
>   calculates the info based on fixed calculations.** If the display driver
>   reports invalid info, GetDeviceCaps returns the invalid info. **Also, if
>   the display driver declines to report info, GetDeviceCaps might
>   calculate incorrect info** because it assumes either fixed DPI (96 DPI)
>   or a fixed size (depending on the info that the display driver did and
>   didn’t provide). **Unfortunately, a display driver that is implemented
>   to the Windows Display Driver Model (WDDM) (introduced in Windows
>   Vista) causes GDI to not get the info, so GetDeviceCaps must always
>   calculate the info.**

So it seems the return value of GetDeviceCaps API may not reflect the real value of the device.